# Completion closure in swift doesn't appear to be firing

Tags: ios, swift

I am following the "Learning Swift" book from O'reilly, and I have some code that looks like:

```
func deleteDocumentAtURL(url: NSURL) {
    NSLog("Got to top of deleteDocumentAtURL, url: \(url)")
    let fileCoordinator = NSFileCoordinator(filePresenter: nil)
    fileCoordinator.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(url, options: .ForDeleting, error: nil, byAccessor: { (urlForModifying) -> Void in
        NSLog("Here I am")
        do {
            NSLog("Got inside deleteDocumentBlock")
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(urlForModifying)

            // Remove the URL from the list
            self.availableFiles = self.availableFiles.filter {
                $0 != url
            }

            // Update the collection
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error deleting", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

When I run this code, which is triggered by clicking a button in the interface, the application hangs. Also, the log inside the do{} is not firing, which makes me think there's a problem with the whole block? Help appreciated.

Comment: Well, is another application also accessing the document?

Comment: @jtbandes it shouldn't be? how would I tell that? Also, why would that prevent me from getting into the block at all?

Comment: Because that's what NSFileCoordinator is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
let fileCoordinator = NSFileCoordinator(filePresenter: nil)
```

is local in the function. The variable is already destroyed, if you finished the function. 
So, the async block can't be executed.

Put **fileCoordinator** as an instance variable to the class.

Comment: No. closure saves all the relevant references\values until it is destroyed.

`Closures can capture and store references to any constants and variables from the context in which they are defined. This is known as closing over those constants and variables. Swift handles all of the memory management of capturing for you.`

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling error and probably have an error

[Documentation for coordinateReadingItemAtURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFileCoordinator_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileCoordinator/coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:):

> outError: On input, a pointer to a pointer for an error object. If a file presenter encounters an error while preparing for this read operation, 
>
> ### that error is returned in this parameter and the block in the reader parameter is not executed.
>
>  If you cancel this operation before the reader block is executed, this parameter contains an error object on output.

add error handler and see if you get an error

```
func deleteDocumentAtURL(url: NSURL) {
    NSLog("Got to top of deleteDocumentAtURL, url: \(url)")
    let fileCoordinator = NSFileCoordinator(filePresenter: nil)
    var error: NSError?
    fileCoordinator.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(url, options: .ForDeleting, error: &error, byAccessor: { (urlForModifying) -> Void in
        NSLog("Here I am")
        do {
            NSLog("Got inside deleteDocumentBlock")
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(urlForModifying)

            // Remove the URL from the list
            self.availableFiles = self.availableFiles.filter {
                $0 != url
            }

            // Update the collection
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error deleting", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    })
    //Error:
    if(error != nil){
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does make sense, but when I tried to apply it to my code, xcode became unhappy and threw an error about separators. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @phildini you mean it won't compile? make sure that my only change is adding `var error :  NSError?` and make sure you send it as `&error` to the function

Comment: So, adding just those things allows it to compile, but I still get the error. :/

Comment: @phildini well, that was the point, that the block was not executed because

Comment: Here's what the function looks like now: https://gist.github.com/phildini/de0a2ab3f84c5e67ae6e3027ba573d33

Comment: If I add the `if (error...` block where you suggested adding it, it doesn't compile.

Comment: @phildini I've edited my code, should compile now, copy paste exactly that code